# Jmeter: how to extract json object of array from repsosne using beanshell post process

Tags: arrays, json, jmeter, beanshell

Im new to jmeter and wanted to extract the array data from json object
i have a Json as below

{
"error": false,
"data": {
"seq": [
"71128dfa",
"cbfda925",
"9d9bfa68",
"0ca86cf2",
"8bc3cfa7",
"4ea9aee3"
],
"request_id": "1db799cf-8f2b-4982-a23e-b2fb95b609b9"
}
}

i need to get the data which is under seq array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Json Extractor to extract it

you need to pass the json path expression to retrieve it

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Grooovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so I would recommend switching to [JSR223 Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor)

If you want the [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) which lives under `seq` attribute you can extract it using the following code:

```
def response = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())

def seq = response.data.seq

vars.put('seq', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(seq).toString())
```

You will be able to refer the extracted value as `${seq}` where required.

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and Producint JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)